# Is there any cheap way to convert from CX4 to RJ45?

Tags: hp-procurve, 10gbethernet, convert, rj45

I have an HP ProCurve 2900 with 2 x CX4 10Gb ports in the back.
And I want to somehow link it with my internet provider 10Gb hub, which only has a 10Gb RJ45 connector.

So far I was only able to find on Google, CX4 to CX4 cables, or 10Gb CX4 network cards, but I am not able to find any cheap converters from CX4 to RJ45.

Any idea where can I find such an adapter, if it exists ?

Thanks

Comment: You might need to brush up your Google skillz, see: https://dcscom.net/data-communications-en/media-converters-en/copper-to-fiber-media-converters-en/10g-media-converters/s-10gt-xfph-media-converter/

Comment: At that amount of money I can by a handful of 10Gb new switches. I'm looking for something with a decent price. up to 50$ if possible. (I've only payed 20$ for the ProCurve  switch)

Comment: @Draco There used to be a D-Link converter for $500 but $50 is a dream (unless you find it used). -CX4 and -T use vastly different encoding and there's only a teeny tiny market, so the price badge is justified.

Answer (score 4):

CX4 is a dead connector and fell into disuse a long time ago.

[image]

The ProCurve 2900 went end-of-life ~13 years go.

Your internet provider is giving you a 10GbE handoff, but you can use a 1GbE port on your existing switch.

If you require 10GbE connectivity, you should plan for a newer switch.

Comment: Yes I know it is an old switch and an old connect. My internet provider service offers speeds up to 3Gb. If I connect it over 1Gb port i loose 2/3 of my bandwidth.

Comment: @Draco Do you need the bandwidth? Then it's a new switch.

Comment: For whoever will be interested, I've managed to find a module for my swich which exposed 2 x SFP+ modules: HP ProCurve 2- Port 10-GbE SFP+ al Module (J9008A) . https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c02620659   and managed to find a second had one for about 70$

Comment: @Yonoss That module is for the 29**10**al switch series. The 29**00** in your question only supports CX4 and X2.